# Secondary displays are blank with nvidia/intel drivers and only display mouse cursor with Nouveau driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

**The issue:**

Secondary displays(monitors) are only displaying the desktop background or are just backlit with no background. The mouse cursor is still visible but dragged/moved windows are not. Screen share with Google Meet does pickup and correctly display all attached monitors without issue when recording my screen.

Occasionally in live boot both displays(internal and external) will mirror without issue but in the display options, mirroring isn't selected and when I unstack the displays there is no way to go back to mirroring.

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried the following where applicable on Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon, XUbuntu 19.10, and Manjaro Juhraya 18.1.4 with a full system reboot after each change.

- Tried installing and using nvidia drivers 440, 435, 430, and 418.
- Tried installing and using nouveau drivers provided.
- Tried using the integrated intel graphics.
- Tried using display port and/or HDMI with both monitors.
- Tried changing the internal display to 60Hz.
- Tried adding display modes with xrandr.

The only way to even get an external display detected is with the nvidia gpu and the nouveau drivers.

**My specs:**

I am using an MSI-GS65-Stealth which has a GForce RTX 2060, Intel Core I7-9750, and a non-touch 240Hz display.

---

I've spent the better part of 6 hours working on this already so any help or ideas would be appreciated.

—-

**UPDATE:**

Swapping to the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and using the latest Nvidia drivers seems to have completely fixed the issue. Unfortunately, I still haven’t found the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While not a perfect fix, this is what has worked for me to successfully resolve the issue.

Use the latest version of Ubuntu 20 LTS and the latest Nvidia drivers.

Always connect the external monitor to the laptop AND make sure the monitor is on **BEFORE** turning on the laptop. It appears as though Linux can only detect and connect to the external monitor if it is on before bootup.

Just a guess but i'm assuming that whatever initialization is happening during bootup is not happening automatically when an external display connected afterwards.